# python orm

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

This is a newbie theory question - I'm just starting to use Python and looking into Django and orm.  Question: If I develop my objects and through additional development modify the base object structures, inheritance, etc. - would Django's ORM solution modify the database automatically OR do I need to perform a conversion (if the app is live)?

So, I start with a basic Phone app
Object person: name, address, city, state, zip, phone
and I change to
Object person: title, name, address, city, state, zip, phone object
Object phone: type, phone #

Do I manually convert via the db and change the code OR does the ORM middleware make the change? and if so - how?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021/version-track-automate-db-schema-changes-with-django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django book covers this issue in [Chapter 5](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/), near the end of the chapter (or bottom of the page, in the web edition). Basically, the rules are:

- When *adding* a field, first add it to the database manually (using, e.g., `ALTER TABLE`) and then add the field to the model. (You can use `manage.py sqlall` to see what SQL statement to execute.)
- When removing a field, remove it from your model and then execute the appropriate SQL statement to remove the column (e.g., an `ALTER TABLE` command), and any join tables that were created.
- Renaming a field is basically a combination of adding/removing fields, as well as copying data.

So to answer your question, in Django's case, no, the ORM  will *not* handle modifications for you -- but they're not that hard to do. See that chapter of the book (linked above) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

As of Django 1.02 (and as of the latest run-up to 1.1 in subversion), there is no automatic "schema migration". Your choices are to drop the schema and have Django recreate it (via manage.py syncdb), or alter the schema by hand yourself.

There are some tools on the horizon for Django schema migration. (I'm watching [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).)

Comment: I'm using South, not just watching it, and it's a much better option than "drop the schema and have Django recreate it" or "alter the schema by hand yourself."

Answer (score 0):

We include a 'version' number in the application name.

Our directories look like this

```
project
    settings.py
    appA_1
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
    appB_1 
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py   
    appB_2
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
```

This shows two versions of appB.  appB_1 was the original version.  When we changed the model, we started by copying the app to create appB_2, and then modified that one.

A `manage.py syncdb` will create the fresh new appB_2.

We have to unload and reload the tables by copying from appB_1 to appB_2.  Once.

Then we can remove appB_1 from the settings.py.  Later we can delete the tables from the database.

Comment: -1 This is a really cumbersome solution compared to using either raw SQL migrations or a tool like django-evolution or South.  I wouldn't recommend it for anyone starting out.