# Is every DDL SQL command reversible? [database version control]

Tags: sql, version-control, migration, ddl

I want to setup a mechanism for tracking DB schema changes, such the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607/mechanisms-for-tracking-db-schema-changes#1666):

> For every change you make to the
>   database, you write a new migration.
>   Migrations typically have two methods:
>   an "up" method in which the changes
>   are applied and a "down" method in
>   which the changes are undone. A single
>   command brings the database up to
>   date, and can also be used to bring
>   the database to a specific version of
>   the schema.

My question is the following: Is every DDL command in an "up" method reversible? In other words, can we always provide a "down" method? Can you imagine any DDL command that can not be "down"ed?

Please, do not consider the typical data migration problem where during the "up" method we have loss of data: e.g. changing a field type from `datetime` (`DateOfBirth`) to `int` (`YearOfBirth`) we are losing data that can not be restored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in sql server every DDL command that i know of is an up/down pair.

Answer (score 2):

Other than loss of data, every migration I've ever done is reversible.   That said, Rails offers a way to mark a migration as "destructive":

> Some transformations are destructive
>   in a manner that cannot be reversed.
>   Migrations of that kind should raise
>   an ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
>   exception in their down method.

See the API documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html).

Comment: Even data is reversable if you store it somewhere like with local yml files (see https://github.com/tomkurt/Reversable-Data-Migration)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've identified cases where you lose data, either by transforming it or simply DROP COLUMN in the "up" migration.

Another example is that you could drop a SEQUENCE object, thus losing its state.  The "down" migration would recreate the sequence, but it would start over at 1.  This could cause duplicate values to be generated by the sequence.  Not a problem if you're performing a migration on an empty database, and you want the sequence to start at 1 anyway, but if you have some number of rows of data, you'd want the sequence to be reset to the greatest value currently in use, which is hard to do reliably, unless you have an exclusive lock on that table.

Any other DDL that is dependent on the state of data in the database has similar problems.  That's probably not a good schema design in the first place, I'm just trying to think of any cases that fit your question.