# Compare tools to generate update script for SQL server

Tags: sql-server, build-process, installation, build-automation

I would like to make the update of the web application as automated as possible.
I'm looking for a tool that can compare two instances of a database and generate an update script for me. As part of the build process create a instance of the last version of the database (ie currently in production) and compare that to what has been changed on the development version.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: See *duplicate* question already asked: [Best tool for auto-generating SQL
> change scripts for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688/best-tool-for-auto-generating-sql-change-scripts-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like [SqlDbDiff](http://sqldbtools.com). Way cheaper than [RedGate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm)

Comment: Nice. I will have to evaluate this one. I'm a long-time Red-Gate user, so this may be refreshing, especially for clients where budget is a concern.

Comment: Very nice! I've had good success with Red-Gate but this one has better value for its price!

Comment: We actually bought this tool.  It's nice, but there are a few usage flow annoyances that would be easy to do and really help make it a better product.  It does not seem like it is being actively developed though.

Answer (score 1):

I answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172055/looking-for-tools-to-export-a-set-of-specific-rows-of-data-creating-insert-scri#172825).

Best of luck! As you will see, I like the [Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) tools.

Answer (score 0):

See

[Mechanisms for tracking DB schema changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607/mechanisms-for-tracking-db-schema-changes#22535)

I believe the [profluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175451/how-do-you-version-your-database-schema#175473) of this question on SO speaks to the lack of a standard solution to this problem.

The great divide in approach is
- write delta scripts
- automate script generation from a "master" instance

It sounds like you want something in the latter camp.

Several such solutions and tools are noted in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

so far, satisfied with RedGate. We use SQL version control + SQL Compare.
I've integrated it with Msbuild and Hudson. So that give us a complete continuous integration solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple more to add to the list:

- [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) (schema compare) and [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) (data compare)
- [Comparison toolset](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver)
- [Adept SQL Diff](http://www.adeptsql.com/)