# What is best tool to compare two SQL Server databases (schema and data)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, compare

I would like to compare two SQL Server databases including schema (table structure) and data in tables too. What is best tool to do this?

Comment: yep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/tool-to-compare-sql-server-tables

Comment: is there anything For SqlSever 2008R2 and Sql Azure ?

Comment: Also not a duplicate as the other question asks for just a table compare not a db

Comment: How about xSQL's [Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/) and [Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/) tools. Completely **free for SQL Server Express** and very reasonably priced for other editions.

Comment: Can we get a tool to downvote the users who mark as duplicate without bothering to post the original links. At least give users opportunity to distinguish between their question, and existing questions. This is the top ranked google search wrt Comparison tools. It has merit

Comment: No more answers are being allowed, but I found that winmerge worked great and was free.

Comment: Use Master Data extension for visual studio ... https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/530c546a-fdd3-4589-b2b2-e3c4aab13fba

Comment: Try TOAD for SQL Server. It's a free trial and the compare schema utility is pretty good. Very simple and it generates a synchronisation script to merge changes from one database to another. To be honest I've tried TableDiff that comes with SQL Server 2005, 2008, etc, and it's horrid.

Comment: No idea why this is marked as duplicated, as the other question is specific about free tool and this not..

Comment: Its actually funny to see that a duplicate has more views and points rather than the first one

Comment: Gotta love stackoverflow. Marked as duplicate to a question that does NOT ask about comparing data. Slowly moderating the site to death, and there is no recourse for obvious abuses like this.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Yes, it is clear the other question is about comparing tables, while mine is about comparing databases. I am sad to see what happens here also. I have voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I am using Red-Gate's software:
 [http://www.red-gate.com](http://www.red-gate.com/)

Comment: SQLCompare is very good.

Comment: Yes - SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare are absolutely essential to our business - good stuff.

Comment: davidsleeps, have you raised this with Red Gate's support engineers? We'd love to diagnose any issues you might have with SQL Compare (I'm SQL Compare's product manager).

Comment: It may be "expensive" (a few hundred dollars), but when you compare that against what you'd pay a developer to spend a day search, learning, and working around the shortcomings in a free tool, I think it's a well worthwhile investment.

Comment: Expensive?  $300 for something that can save you dozens of hours per year.  Even at the lowest global developer rates this is a bargain.

Comment: SQL Compare has become a much better product over the years but still not the best one. I tried many of these tools over the last 10 years and the best one is SQL Delta with its superbly accurate script generator, the second is AdeptSql (only because its data compare tool does not work properly when there is a lot of referential integ. constraints), red gate is a distant 3rd along with many other tools

Comment: The tool is really good - but as it was told earlier very expensive. I've choosen the alternative - dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server from Devart. The functionality is almost the same. It suits all my needs and is much cheaper.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer this question duplicates, this functionality is built into SQL Server as TableDiff.exe. It's worth trying the built in tools first before paying for a licences.

Answer (score 247):

I use schema and data comparison functionality built into the latest version **Microsoft Visual Studio** Community Edition (Free) or Professional / Premium /  Ultimate edition. Works like a charm!

[image: img]

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS108

**Red-Gate's SQL data comparison tool** is my second alternative:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [spaanjaars.com](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/Articles/NLayer45/Part10/Figure10-5_Red_Gate_SQL_Compare_Results.png))</sub>

- http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: I've had these sitting on my desktop for years and didn't even know it!  Thanks for this tip.

Comment: I also found that Visual Studio's Data and Schema comparison tool works better than Red-Gates's one (it syncs schema more accurately)

Comment: Missing data compare in VS2012?  Update from Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Comment: Microsoft's tooling is only available in the Premium (expensive) and Ultimate (ridiculously expensive) editions of visual studio

Comment: @OrionEdwards this tool is availible in vs Professional as well.
have it installed and works great!

Comment: Visual Studio tool works great as long as you don't try to make comparison betwwen different versions of SQL Server. In this case, it will just refuse to compare, although comparison and update is actually possible

Comment: I have had Visual Studio 2013 crash on me multiple times while trying to use the built-in tools to sync data from our Prod database to the Test database.  It works good for small batches, but when you try to sync the entire database.....  well, good luck.  RedGate's tool has worked perfectly for me, being able to handle the heavy lifting to sync the entire DB's data.  (And it seems to be faster as well.)

Comment: I used Redgate before. It's so useful but at first it's so expensive and the most important thing about that is generating so many unwanted script specially when you change schema for example add column between other columns in table. If you don't hesitate about clarify and in yourself control scripts and you have enough money then Redgate is good tools. But for me the VSSQLTools is good and proper. Thanks and +1 to Konstantin and Thanks again and +1 to @Dan Esparza for data comparing link for VS2012.

Comment: I forgot about that feature! I got too used to RedGate at work. Now I can use this VS feature when working on my personal stuff. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you - I didn't even know it was there! The tool is almost effortless and the ability to copy data (backwards) to a previous version is a real plus, since I couldn't seem to import the data using import with the versions I was using. Thanks again!

Comment: The data comparison functionality in VS is very powerful but it lacks a major feature.

You can select which tables to compare, or drill down on the columns for each table. That's very useful when you have a big database with a lot of moving parts, but you only want to export a specific subset. Also the columns are different on live, so naturally you want to ignore that.

The problem is you can't save those filters. So imagine what a nightmare would be to do this on a 100 tables datasource. Not to mention error-prone...

Comment: @Christian you can save the data or schema comparison settings into a file, then instead of starting a new comparison over again, you just open a corresponding `.dcmp` or `.scmp` file.

Comment: This does not support SQL 2000 I believe. Any idea of a tool that support SQL Server 2000 data and schema comparison?

Comment: Thank you, never knew about this feature in VS, folks **Note: Two types: 1. New Data Comparison 2. New Schema Comparison**, To start comparing , Go to Tools ==> SQL Server , i was trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/175450/2218697) sql query to check the source and target database with multiple select statements, is there not a `sql query` to compare complete database ?

Comment: Works like a charm in VS2017. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! First time saw, _the difference_ between _schemas_, **visually**, Thanks a bunch Konstantin!

Comment: Is this not in SSMS? That's odd if it isn't.

Answer (score 141):

I like [Open DBDiff](https://github.com/OpenDBDiff/OpenDBDiff).

While not the most complete tool, it works great, it's free, and it's very easy to use.

Comment: Simple, Easy and it work. My choice to replicate differencies from one database to another.

Comment: I have been searching for a tool like this for years. I have tested plenty free tools against two of my databases, and this was the ONLY free tool generating the a proper synchronization upgrade script. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This does not compare DATA

Comment: This is the worst database comparison tool I have come across. It does not save the preferences correctly, it often bombs out. It does not save the SQL instances you've used and then scans the network everytime for all PCs that it then lists - thus you have to copy and paste the instances every time and sit and wait until the network has been scanned before you can use it. This will probably work on very small databases but i couldn't get it to work once and a larger db. Its free, but so is malaria.

Comment: Note that it CAN compare data, but only for single tables. I personally found this useful, but if you need to diff many tables or large tables it probably is not sufficient.

Comment: It doesn't work ok in sql server 2014

Comment: @Daveo select a table and in the right navigation pan you will see the compare data option being enabled.

Comment: It doesn't compare permissions on objects :-(

Comment: it worked pretty good for me on SQL Server 2014 and 2017

Answer (score 75):

**SQL Admin Studio** from http://www.simego.com/Products/SQL-Admin-Studio is now free, lets you manage your SQL Database, **SQL Compare and Synchronise**, **Data Compare and Synchronise** and much more. Also supports SQL Azure and some MySQL Support too.

[UPDATE: Yes I am the Author of the above program, as it's now Free I just wanted to Share it with the community]

Comment: It's a little rough about the edges compared to some of the pay offerings, but it does work, and a good bit cheaper (as it's free) +1.

Comment: Data Sync Studio doesn't seem to be free anymore.

Comment: Has all the features you need making it the best free solution IMO (data sync may not be free but I prefer to backup/restore in the instance I need data)

Comment: This does not work with sqlite as an FYI to anyone

Comment: Good job @SeanCleaver, Some issues with tables with non-primary key as clustered index otherwise overall 9/10.

Comment: Your data compare works brilliantly with SQL server. Not so much luck with the schema compare because the column order can't be ignored but the data compare is what I was really looking for and it worked perfectly with different order columns.

Comment: free now and supports ***SQL Server 2016*** ?

Comment: https://www.simego.com/install/sql-tools not found

Comment: I got the software from https://download.cnet.com/SQL-Admin-Studio-64-Bit/3000-10254_4-75700837.html

Answer (score 13):

I'm partial to [AdeptSQL](http://www.adeptsql.com/).  It's clean and intuitive and it DOESN'T have the one feature that scares the hell out of me on a lot of similar programs.  One giant button that it you push it will automatically synchronize EVERYTHING without so much as a by-your-leave.  If you want to sync the changes you have to do it yourself and I like that.

Comment: +1 Adept SQL Diff is a superb piece of software and relatively cheap

Comment: I do agree. It's very fast and reliable at a very convenient cost. We use it at work.

Comment: Lol I know - in the Visual Studio tool the button to sync is right next to the generate script button. I haven't clicked either yet but still scared!

Comment: This is one of the best tools... but is no longer available and is now unable to connect to some SQL servers.

Answer (score 8):

There is one tool with source code available at 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool

That should give flexibility  as code is available.

Answer (score 6):

[dbghost](http://www.innovartis.co.uk/) is the best i have used to date.  one of the best features i have seen is that it will generate SQL code to go between versions of a database based on the SQL you keep in source control, as well as a database.  simple and easy to use.

Comment: I've used DbGhost for 10 years and it's never let me down. The support they provide is second to none

Answer (score 4):

I've used SQL Delta before (http://www.sqldelta.com/), it's really good. Not free however, not sure how prices compare to Red-Gates

Comment: Solid product, used it for a few years.  Nice interface and doesn't add install a whole other bunch of junk that you may not want.  Price is reasonable (single license for $370)

Answer (score 4):

Try DBComparer, it's free and fast:

http://dbcomparer.com/

Comment: This tool is very iffy. For example, it does a reverse engineer of both databases and then it throws up many tables and views that it claims are different.  However, what is actually different is the way the CREATE scripts look.  

For example, it says a view is different because the one comes up as:
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewName

and the other db comes up as 
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewName]

Comment: Couldn't get this to work at all. Literally took hours to compare a DB, even after deselecting most options that it needs to compare.

Comment: Doesn't work with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Not comparing data

Answer (score 3):

Database Workbench can made it too

http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php

> Cross database development
>
> Use the Schema Compare and Migration
>   Tools to compare testing and deployed
>   databases, migrate existing databases
>   to different database systems.

you can also made it with database Comparer

http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/dbcomparer/dbcomparer.asp

I use it for Firebird and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

Try [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/). It can compare and sync any databases, even very large ones. Quick, easy, always delivers a correct result.
Try it on your database and comment upon the product.

We can recommend you a reliable SQL comparison tool that offer 3 time’s faster comparison and synchronization of table data in your SQL Server databases. It's [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/) and [dbForge Schema Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/)

Main advantages:

- Speedier comparison and synchronization of large databases
- Support of native SQL Server backups
- Custom mapping of tables, columns, and schemas
- Multiple options to tune your comparison and synchronization
- Generating comparison and synchronization reports

Plus free 30-day trial and risk-free purchase with 30-day money back guarantee.

Comment: Please add "a full disclosure". (Devart makes dbForge.)

Comment: My choice is Devart's SQL Data and Schema Compare tools. Red Gate products are good too, but Devart's are much cheaper and also very professional. Thank you guys!

Comment: I have used this and it worked great for me. So far I am a fan. It's not free at all, but rather, a free trial.

Comment: can attest, really good.

Answer (score 1):

We are using an inhouse developed solution that is basicly a procedure with arguments of what you want included in the comparision (SP's, Full SP code, table structure, defaults, indices, triggers.. etc)

Depending on your needs and budget, it might be a good way to go for you as well.

It is quite easily developed as well, then we just redirect output of procedure to textfiles and do text comparisions between the files.

One good thing about it is that its possible to save the output in source control.

/B

Answer (score 1):

I've used Red Gate's tools and they are superb.
However, if you can't spend any money you could try [Open DBDiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/) to compare schemas.

Comment: dead link. please provide another link.

Comment: This seems to be it:  https://github.com/OpenDBDiff/OpenDBDiff

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with AdeptSQL if you're using MSSQL. It's the least good looking but the most talented db compare tool amongst the ones I've tried. It can compare both the structure and the data. It tells you which tables exist on one db but does not exist on the other, compares the structure and data of the common ones and it can produce the script to synchronize the two. It's not free but has a 30 day trial (as far as I can remember)

Answer (score 0):

I tried [OpenDiff Tool](http://www.ginktage.com/2012/04/open-dbdiff-for-sql-server-2008/) . Great tool that is free and easy to use .