# How do I obtain a list of all schemas in a Sql Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to retrieve a list of all schemas in a given Sql Server database. Using the `ADO.NET` schema retrieval API, I get a list of all collections but there is no collection for 'Schemas'.
I could traverse the `'Tables'`, `'Procedures'` collections (and others if required) and obtain a list of unique schema names but isn't there a easier/shorter way of achieving the same result?

Example: For the standard `'AdventureWorks'` database I would like to obtain the following list - `dbo,HumanResources,Person,Production,Purchasing,Sales` (I've omitted the other standard schem names like `db_accessadmin`,`db_datareader` etc)

Edit: I can get the list of schemas by querying the system view - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` but would prefer using the schema API as first choice.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

For 2005 and later, these will both give what you're looking for.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.schemas
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

For 2000, this will give a list of the *databases* in the *instance*.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

That's the "backward incompatability" noted in @Adrift's answer.

In SQL Server 2000 (and lower), there aren't really "schemas" as such, although you can use roles as namespaces in a similar way.  In that case, this may be the closest equivalent.

```
SELECT * FROM sysusers WHERE gid <> 0
```

Comment: I tried using this on a sql 2000 server, but I did not get all schemas returned. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I don't have a 2000 instance around for testing -- and I thought *I* was a real hanger-on!  Remember that 2000 doesn't have actual "schemas" like later versions, so what you're really listing is roles.  Try just `SELECT * FROM sysusers` and see if you see the identifiers you're looking for.

Comment: I read up on it and the SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA is actually not a good idea to use as far as the sources i read said. A far better method is to execute the master table stored procedure "sp_databases". It works for both 2000 and 2005 (tested both), and in my case returned the correct result every single time.

Comment: @evilfish, thanks for the note.  Just to be clear, this was a question about listing the *schemas* in a database, where it sounds like you wanted to list the *databases* in an instance.  This is confused somewhat by the fact that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` has served both functions in different versions of MS SQL.

Answer (score 15):

Try this query here:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas
```

This will give you the name and schema_id for all defines schemas in the database you execute this in.

I don't really know what you mean by querying the "schema API" - these `sys.` catalog views (in the `sys` schema) are your best bet for any system information about databases and objects in those databases.

Comment: cool. Your query seems to do the trick too. Wonder whats more efficient - querying sys.schema or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA view? By 'Schema API' I mean the standard SqlConnection.GetSchema' calls rather than explicitly issuing a query.

Comment: The "sys." catalog views are probably a tad more efficient and faster, but they're SQL Server specific. INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are a database-agnostic ANSI standard for querying database metadata, but as they were designed by a standards committee...... you get the idea.....

Comment: may be not related , i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/175450/2218697) with multiple select statements for `PK,FK,D,C,V,UQ` etc to compare source and target database, but then i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/685073/2218697) feature in VS, but  is there not a `sql query` to compare complete source and target database ?

Answer (score 6):

You can also query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA view:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

I believe querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views is recommended as they protect you from changes to the underlying sys tables.  From the SQL Server 2008 R2 Help:

> Information schema views provide an
>   internal, system table-independent
>   view of the SQL Server metadata.
>   Information schema views enable
>   applications to work correctly
>   although significant changes have been
>   made to the underlying system tables.
>   The information schema views included
>   in SQL Server comply with the ISO
>   standard definition for the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Ironically, this is immediately preceded by this note:

> Some changes have been made to the
>   information schema views that break
>   backward compatibility. These changes
>   are described in the topics for the
>   specific views.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT s.name + '.' + ao.name
       , s.name
FROM sys.all_objects ao
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = ao.schema_id
WHERE ao.type='u';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Sql Server Management Studio, you can obtain a list of all schemas, create your own schema or remove an existing one by browsing to:

Databases - [Your Database] - Security - Schemas

[[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following query to get Schemas for a specific Database user:

```
select s.schema_id, s.name as schema_name
from sys.schemas s
inner join sys.sysusers u on u.uid = s.principal_id
where u.name='DataBaseUserUserName'
order by s.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following query:

```
SELECT s.name AS schema_name,
u.name AS schema_owner
FROM sys.schemas s
INNER JOIN sys.sysusers u ON u.uid = s.principal_id
ORDER BY s.name;
```