# how can i see all the scheme in the sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I obtain a list of all schemas in a Sql Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719623/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-schemas-in-a-sql-server-database)

I manage to see all the schemas in the sql server 2000.  I used the following statement

```
show search_path
```

But it failed.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

For more info please refer link [How do I obtain a list of all schemas in a Sql Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719623/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-schemas-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: In SQL 2000, the above referenced command gives a list of Databases, not Schemas.