# get schemas in a specific databse in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get the schemas list in specific database in MS SQL server, not all schemas list in entire MS SQL server
EX:
i will get list of Db's like A,B,C from ms sql server.Now i need to fetch all schema list from A

I need a query for that
can i get some help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I obtain a list of all schemas in a Sql Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719623/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-schemas-in-a-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using the `sys.schemas` catalog view:

```
USE A;
SELECT name 
FROM sys.schemas;
```

3-part name example:

```
SELECT name 
FROM A.sys.schemas;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain all schemas from specific database like this

```
USE Database_Name
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas
```

Read link below to have a better understanding

[How do I obtain a list of all schemas in a Sql Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719623/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-all-schemas-in-a-sql-server-database)