# How to produce an incremental DDL script?

Tags: sql-server, ddl

Mine is a SQL Server database.

Suppose I have two DDL scripts, one old and one new. I want to compare the old and the new scripts and generate an incremental script which can be run on the database of old script and finally a database that represents the new script is prepared.

Is there such a tool / utility?

Answer (score 1):

Many

Possibly the best known is the [Red Gate Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) which costs money.

There are several*free* tools highlighted in these 2 threads though (I won't copy paste)

- [What is best tool to compare two SQL Server databases (schema and data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685053/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases-schema-and-data)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377388/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-red-gates-tools-like-sql-compare