# Is there a script available to take backup of SQL azure database with data?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

is there a script available which take back up of database which is in SQL Azure???

Comment: There is a service that does this (currently free).  See here: http://dacguy.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/sql-azure-importexport-service-ctp-now-available/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, backup like you know from MS SQL 2008 is not supported on Azure SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx

Redgate has a free backup tool http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/

For information on how to do backup and restore using BCP.exe and http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ then see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/kk-KZ/ssdsgetstarted/thread/b2a3c161-96b1-4201-ac46-a747e1806be1  .

Answer (score 1):

There is a great new product from [www.bluesyntax.net](http://www.bluesyntax.net/) which has a couple of options.  It only costs 50 USD.  There are options to backup to a local file or back up to blob storage.

They will give you a 30 day Evaluation Key if you ask.

In my opinion it is well worth a look.  I am certainly going to be purchasing a licence.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an export feature you can use from the Azure Management Portal to produce a BACPAC file which can then be imported as  a local database. I found [an excellent blog post](http://dacguy.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/sql-azure-importexport-service-has-hit-production/) (from the same blog [@dunnry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375911/dunnry) mentions in his comment on your question) that details the steps required and I have and summarised them in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11212055/575530).

If you do not mind the backup being on Azure too then look at the tSQL command

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDBBackup23_6_12 AS COPY OF MyDB
```