# Error while importing bacpak in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, bacpac

I'm getting this error while importing bacpac file from windows azure

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Count not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Internal Error.  The internal target platform type SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider
does not support schema file version '2.5'.
```

Most of the help online suggests upgrading SSDT, but I have the latest version of SSDT for VS2012 already installed

Comment: SSDT Version is From **July'14 update**.  Also **SqlPackage.exe** cannot be used as it expects **dacpac** instead of **bacpac**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update** - with a number of new features including Query Store, it's now best to use the SQL Server Management Studio Preview to import. In some cases this will be necessary given updated features in the bacpac file. You can install this from its [download page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx). On that download page choose "Download SQL Server Management Studio  Preview" to install.

**Original Answer**
The best solution is to install SQL Server Management Studio 2014 from the [Express download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299). On that download page choose "MgmtStudio 32BIT\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe" installer when clicking the download link. SSMS 2014 contains a more recent DacFx version that supports version 2.5 and has full support for SQL Server 2005-2014 dbs, along with Azure DBs.

A few notes on DacFx / SqlPackage:

- Installing the latest SSDT won't fix the issue since SSDT no longer installs Dac DLLs in a shared location. Instead it installs them under the Visual Studio install dir (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120).
- To update DacFx binaries used in SSMS to the latest version you must install the DacFramework.msi directly. You can download the latest version for 2014 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43370) (this will update the location used by SSMS 2014), or if you have to use SSMS 2012 the last version compatible with that is found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39976).
- SqlPackage.exe does support bacpacs. You need to use the Import/Export actionsfor bacpacs rather than the Extract/Publish actions used for dacpacs.

Comment: Used the second option Update Dac framework for SSMS 2012 and it did resolved my issue. Thanx.

Comment: Before this SQLpackage said there is no action Import. Didn't tried after Dacframework update.

Comment: the latest version for 2014 (in the second bullet point) is now [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45886)

Comment: Your solution works - "SQL Server Management Studio November 2015 preview" !! Thanks so much.

Comment: I had to install sql server management studio 2016 for it to work https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will not directly restore. As you already install "SQL Server Data Tools", please check links.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66a4dfeb-c626-45eb-af3c-00e7e5996203/bacpac-file-import-from-windows-azure-fails?forum=ssdt

[Azure SQL Database Bacpac Local Restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/sql-azure-bacpac-local-restore)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsazure/en-us/36035d1e-fda8-4388-99c4-ba2ff7c5a5e1/new-sql-azure-bacpac-format-not-working-with-sql-2012

http://saransh77.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/part-1-how-to-manually-backup-azure-sql-database-and-import-in-on-premise-sql-server/

Comment: This is not working as I am getting the same error 
Internal Error.  The internal target platform type SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider
does not support schema file version '2.5'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that something has recently changed Azure side to break even using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.  I had to install the Cumulative Update 5 onto SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to get this working again.  Looks like Cumulative Update 6 is out so you could also try that.

Comment: Yes, a recent change means that if Query Store is enabled on the Azure SQL database and you export using the Import/Export service you'll need  the latest Preview release of SSMS to install. You can download and install this from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx. It is fully backwards compatible with previous SQL Server versions

Comment: I can confirm that CU6 for SQL Server 2014 SP1 works. It can be found here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3144524

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my SQL Server 2012 with [SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351) and then I could actually Import BACPAC files from Azure. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this has been there for a while but those who have still this problem, this happens because of having an older version of Microsoft® SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework.

Installing the latest version solved the problem.

At the time I am writing this is the latest and I was using an older which was incompatible with the bacpac file I was trying to import.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898