# When Deleting/Re-importing a .bacpac file from v12 Azure SQL Database in to the same server tables are not imported

Tags: sql-server, azure, bacpac

Here is what I did:

1. Created export (.bacpac saved to storage account) of "my-db" Azure SQL Database using (new) management portal.
2. Deleted the database "my-db" (using new Azure Portal) from "my-v12-azure-db-server".
3. Again from the new Azure portal, attempted to import the .bacpac file from step one into "my-v12-azure-db-server".

Result: The database with the correct name is created, but it is empty.  There are no errors returned through the UI.  It contains none of the tables from the original database.

Other Things Tried: I was able to successfully import the same .bacpac file into other v12 db servers on the same Azure subscription.  I also tried deleting the database server and re-creating it, but the same thing happens when I bring it back.  In addition, I attempted deleting the db server using powershell, but after recreating it I had the same result.

Ideally I'd like to keep the same db server name and database name so that I do not have to change connection strings in source.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the problem could be a bug (or feature unknown to me) within the azure portal.

As a workaround, I was able to update a local installation of SQL Server Management Studio 2014 to the newest patch and then import from my box using SSMS.  I will try to remember to update my response if I get a better response from Microsoft Premier Support.

Cumulative update package 6 for SQL Server 2014:
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3031047

To perform the import from local SSMS to the Azure v12 Database:
[Azure SQL Database Bacpac Local Restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/sql-azure-bacpac-local-restore)

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the import/export status in the SQL DB server after ordering bacpac restore? You can do it in the new portal.

Also, I found that one time the restore operation had restored the backup into a database with the .bacpac name and not the name I choose in the portal

Comment: Yes, I did check the status of the import in the portal and each import attempt completed successfully.  Also note that the new portal will automatically name the database the same as the .bacpac file name, but this can be overridden by changing the text just before initiating the import.  The portal User Interface only verifies that the database name does not already exist on the server before it allows the import.  This is the reason that I had to delete the original database before attempting my import the first time.