# Get local copy of SQL Server hosted on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have a small (few hundred MB) SQL Server database running on RDS. I've spent several hours trying to get a copy of it onto my local SQL Server 2014 instance. All of the following fail. Any ideas what might work?

1. `Task -> Backup` fails because it doesn't give my admin account permission to backup to a local drive.
2. `Copy Database` fails during create package with `While trying to find a folder on SQL an OLE DB error was encountered with error code 0x80040E4D`
3. From SSMS, while connected to the RDS server, running `BACKUP DATABASE`.  This fails with message `BACKUP DATABASE permission denied in database 'MyDB'`.  Even after running `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator'` for the connected user.
4. `General scripts` generates a 700MB `.sql` file. Running that with `sqlcmd -i` fails at some point after producing plausible `.mdf` and `.ldf` files that can't be mounted on the local server (probably because the sqlcmd failed to complete and unlock them).

Comment: Create the databases locally manually first and get that working. Then use _Tasks / Generate Scripts. In Advanced, select _Types of data to script = Schema and Data_ and run the resultant script. It would've helped if you'd posted the error messages originally. If this doesn't work, post the error

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I was able to eventually get that (#4) working in this case (following a series of reboots of the machine and services to get the MDF to attach), but it's not scalable.

Comment: Do you really mean "can't be automated"? If you were to post the error perhaps we could help.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - The OS thinks they're locked by an MS SQL process, and the MS SQL Server thinks it doesn't have or can't get the lock.  I could spend time determining a minimal sequence to get them mounted, but for any significant amount of data this seems to be the most kludgy approach.

Comment: If you post the code with the problem and the error maybe we can help. Normally you just issue a CREATE DATABASE and then USE it, but you still have to nominate a path anyway so the way I see it, there is some degree of config required

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @AndréBonna - Sorry, haven't had a chance to try your solution yet.  Will update when I do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWS has finally provided a reasonably easy means of doing this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html):  It requires an S3 bucket.

After creating a bucket called `rds-bak` I ran the following stored procedure in the RDS instance:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
   @source_db_name='MyDatabase',
   @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::rds-bak/MyDatabase.bak',
   @overwrite_S3_backup_file=1;
```

The following stored procedure returns the status of the backup request:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='MyDatabase'
```

Once it finished I downloaded the `.bak` file from S3 and imported it into a local SQL Server instance using the SSMS `Restore Database...` wizard!

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS Import Export Wizard can generate a package to duplicate a whole set of tables. (It's not the sort of Copy Database function that relies on files - it makes a package with data flow components for each table.)

It's somewhat brittle but can be made to work :-)

SSMS Generate Scripts feature can often fail with any large data set as the script for all the data is just to large/verbose. This method never scripts out the data.

Comment: I was never able to get SSIS to work against RDS.  However, I did manage to get Generate Scripts to work: In `Advanced` settings change `Types of data to script` from `Schema only` to `Schema and data`.  Yes, that did create a (now) 1.2GB plain-text file for my 200MB database.  But I was able to get it loaded to a local server without too many warnings in 15 minutes using `sqlcmd -i scripted.sql -d MyDatabase -x`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://github.com/andrebonna/RDSDump

It is a C#.NET Console Application that search for the latest origin database Snapshot, restore it on a temporary RDS instance, generate a BACPAC file, upload it to S3 and delete the temporary RDS instance.

You can transform your RDS snapshot into a BACPAC file, that can be downloaded and imported onto your local SQL Server 2014 instance using the feature answered here ([Azure SQL Database Bacpac Local Restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847189/azure-sql-database-bacpac-local-restore))

Answer (score 0):

Redgate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare are invaluable for these types of things. They are not cheap (but worth every penny imo). But if this is a one-time thing, you could use the 14 day trial and see how it behaves for you.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/