# Cannot import SQL Azure bacpac to 2016 CTP

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I'm very familiar with the process of exporting from Azure SQL V12 down to my dev box and then importing  to my local sql (2014) instance. I'm spinning up a new Win10 box and have installed the SQL 2016 CTP. I'm connecting to that same Azure instance and can operate against it -- and can export a .bacpac just as with 2014.

But when I try to import to local I'm getting:

```
Could not import package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [FOO33_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [FOO33_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Address_dbo.User_idUser". The conflict occurred in database "FOO33", table "dbo.User", column 'idUser'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
PRINT N'Checking constraint: FK_dbo.Address_dbo.User_idUser [dbo].[Address]';

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Address_dbo.User_idUser];
```

Comment: So what? SQL Server 2016 CTP, being a CTP, is not fully supported by other productrs? Is there any surprise in here?

Comment: it says "Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Address_dbo.User_idUser". The conflict occurred in database "FOO33", table "dbo.User", column 'idUser'"

Comment: Try resolving the error

Comment: @justSteve , I got the same error form production to local import, did you find the solution ? if yes, it would be helpful if you  give an update on how you solved this issue.

Comment: I've seen a handful of occasions where an error was reported but the import had succeeded. Also try just re-running the op.

Comment: As per @justSteve's comment, I have been receiving this error multiple times - but every time, the import works correctly. Seems this error is Fake News! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this question was also asked and answered on MSDN, I will share here.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0b025206-5ea4-4ecb-b475-c7fabdb6df64/cannot-import-sql-azure-bacpac-to-2016-ctp?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Text from linked answer:

I suspect what's going wrong here is that the export operation was performed using a DB instance that was changing while the export was on-going.  This can cause the exported table data to be inconsistent because, unlike SQL Server's physical backup/restore, exports do not guarantee transactional consistency.  Instead, they're essentially performed by connecting to each table in the database in turn and running select *.  When a foreign key relationship exists between two tables and the read table data is inconsistent, it results in an error during import after the data is written to the database and the import code attempts to re-enable the foreign key.  We suggest using the database copy mechanism (create database copyDb as copy of originalDb), which guarantees a copy with transactional consistency, and then exporting from the non-changing database copy.

Comment: Avoid answering with just a link to the answer. This is a main principle of SO.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't import either.