# Importing Azure .bacpac to my local 2014 SQL server no-longer working

Tags: sql-server, azure

I used to be able to download a SQL backup `.bacpac` file and load it on my local SQL server instance and call it copyX by using command prompt and typing:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin
```

enter, then

```
.\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Import /SourceFile:"C:\path\MyBackUp.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=copyX; Integrated Security=true;"
```

Now I get:

> *** A project which specifies Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server
>   2014. Verifying deployment plan Analyzing deployment plan Importing package schema and data into database Updating database
>   *** Error importing database:Could not import package. Warning SQL0: A project which specifies Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 as the target
>   platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014.
>   Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State
>   1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ';'. Error SQL72045: Script execution
>   error.  The executed script: CREATE MASTER KEY;

Putting up due to the many issues encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- [Install](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/1/A/41AD6EDE-9794-44E3-B3D5-A1AF62CD7A6F/sql16_sp2_dlc/en-us/SqlLocalDB.msi) [SQL server 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841450/1452172) and import into that because the database scoped credential feature is only supported in [SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL databases](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0096b655-be5f-4b44-a451-df9de6effbc1/import-of-bacpac-failed-to-sql-server-due-to-credential-on-storage-account?forum=sqltools). Otherwise you might see:

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 195, Level 15, State
>   10, Procedure spX, Line 18 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in
>   function name.

- [Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100297) [DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15) because there is a known [compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46736185/1452172) otherwise you will see:

> Unable to connect to master or target server 'copyX'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'copyX'.

- Remove SQL credentials from .bacpac model.xml and update origin.xml hash the [long way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531532/1452172) or the [short way using](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100297) a [powershell script](https://github.com/yochananrachamim/AzureSQL/blob/master/RemoveMasterKeyFrombacpac.zip?raw=true). Otherwise you might see:

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 102, Level 15, State
>   1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ';'. Error SQL72045: Script execution
>   error. The executed script: CREATE MASTER KEY;

Open a normal command prompt window and type:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin
```

Then type

```
.\SqlPackage.exe /Action:Import /SourceFile:"C:\path\MyBackUp-patched.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=ONO2012-LAPTOP\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=copyX; Integrated Security=true;"
```

Comment: You can accept it as answer.This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you