# How to download a SQL backup from Microsoft Azure without a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups

The only option i could find in the Azure Portal, is to export a copy of my database to a azure storage account which i don't have. So i wonder, is there any other way of exporting my database to my laptop machine?

Comment: just curious about not having a storage account. Given that they're free to create. Is there a specific issue/reason?

Comment: Thank you for telling me. I just assumed that they are not free. :D

Comment: Yup - trivial to create. *Note - you still pay for storage used, which runs a few pennies / gb / month. But if all you're doing is storing or transferring the occasional backup...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [SQL Server Management Studio for that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/) - creating BACPAC and saving that to the local disk is the common solution for backing the database up.

Comment: Can i export everything this way? Like Column properties, constraints, keys, stored procedures, triggers or only the data in my tables?

Comment: "A BACPAC is a related artifact that encapsulates the database schema as well as the data stored in the database." [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx). And more relevant link than i used in the answer - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-export-bacpac-ssms/

Comment: And that [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server) is good as well (ve-e-ery old, but has a detailed information and some approaches that may be used even now).

Comment: I've seen that one. That's why i asked if "everything" gets exported the way you suggested. I have already exported it successfully the way you suggested it. Thank you. :)