# Want to select data from other azure database and insert into our server database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've two different SQL database servers: one on my Local server and the other is on Microsoft Azure. I want to Copy data from SQL Server on Azure into my local database.

My considerations:

- Both database servers are with SQL server authentication.
- The size of Azure SQL database is 2.4GB (Only one or two tables have most of data(90% data))

Note: I want to perform this in SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As the data is large (2.4GB), I would suggest you to export data from the SQL DB on Azure and then import it in Local database.

While copying the data online from one Server to Another - chances are that the Network goes down and you will have to start again and this may happen several times, you never know.

Instead, you should export the data into a file and then import it.

Alternatively, you can refer to this thread:

[How do I copy SQL Azure database to my local development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server)

Answer (score 0):

From on-premises SQL Server, you can use linked servers and 4-part names to point to a database in Azure SQL DB using a datasource which would look like this - `[YourAzureServerName@database.windows.net].[YourDatabaseName].[YourSchemaName].[YourTableName]`

For more details please check this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/).

But, I would suggest to use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database) if your sole purpose is to copy data from Azure db to On-premise db.