# How can I make a copy from an Azure SQL Database into my local ubuntu machine?

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, ubuntu

I have a SQL Server 2017 running on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, and I was also provided with a database hosted on Azure.

What I'm trying to do is to get a local copy of that database so that I can work upon it without messing with the real/production database.

Most of the examples I run into are made through the SSMS such as [this one](https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks140/).

I also tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017) - without success so far.

I've been the whole day trying to figure this out.
Any hand on how can I achieve this on a ubuntu machine?

-- EDIT --

When I tried to do what the [docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017), I get this error:

> Statement 'BACKUP DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Apparently, it has to do with Azure itself:
http://sqlazuretutorials.com/wordpress/sql-statements-not-supported-for-sql-azure/

Comment: why without success? what is the problem? please be more precise

Comment: Sorry, I just explained it a little bit further. See the edit.

Comment: and for the ssms approach?

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu machine. Therefore I can't use it since it's only available for Windows.

Comment: Export the database to blog storage and download it. Itll give you a bacpac file which you can jmport.

Comment: this has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server

Comment: Oh, sorry, @jww I'll keep that in mind for the next time.

Comment: @StefanPrugg, the problem with that answer is that it requires a Windows environment. I already posted the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what I did was that I made use of [Azure Data Studio](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio) along with its extension [SQL Server Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-import-extension?view=sql-server-2017) which has this feature for exporting and importing .bacpac files as in SSMS as mentioned [here](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/01/09/the-january-release-of-azure-data-studio-is-now-available/).