# Can I create a Replication Between Azure Sql Database and Sql Server 2012 (local server)?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a Sql Database in Azure Cloud and I have a Sql Server Database in another server outside the Azure Cloud. I want to configurate a replication between my Azure Sql DataBase and the Sql Server outside the Cloud.

It can be possible?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate from Azure SQL to on-premises SQL or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configurate a replication between your Azure SQL Database and the SQL Server outside the Cloud.

T**here are many ways can help your copy your SQL server database to Azure SQL database**:

1. If your database is not very large, [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017) to
   help you migrate your database from SQL server to Azure SQL Server.
2. Azure Database Migration Service: [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to a single database or pooled database
   in Azure SQL Database offline using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
3. SSMS, right click databse-->`Tasks`-->`Deploy Database to Azure SQL
   database`

**Configurate a replication from  Azure SQL Database and the SQL Server outside the Cloud**:

For example:

1. Export your Azure SQL database as bacpac file and restore it in your
   SQL server.

Reference:

- Azure SQL database: [Export an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC
  file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)
- SQL Server: [Import a BACPAC File to Create a New User Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-2017)

You also can reference this blog: [How do I copy SQL Azure database to my local development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475306/how-do-i-copy-sql-azure-database-to-my-local-development-server)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you dude. :)

Comment: You're welcome,@YoniCastañeda . If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Neither of these are replication options, they're one-offs (that can admittedly be run repeatedly)