# Compare a stored procedure with multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I need to compare a stored procedure in my DEV database with multiple databases in PROD environment (20+).
Any ideas about tools to do that? 
I'm using "SQL Delta 5" to compare two DBs. For multiple DBs (1->N) I was thinking in the command line feature. What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is best tool to compare two SQL Server databases (schema and data)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685053/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases-schema-and-data)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that use [Redgate Schema compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). It's a good tools in order to compare schema of two database together.

Comment: We got multi branch environment on dev, so we need to merge and deploy on every production/staging/testing environment. I completely agree with you the Redgate toolbelt is one of my favourite helper for productivity purposes when comparing and deploying