# Can I use SQL Server Project to compare differences ONLY in certain stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Let's say I have x number of stored procs in my SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2015.

e.g. 5 stored procedures.

I want to do a comparison between these 5 stored procedures and what's on my database server. I just want to compare what differences there are between the 5 stored procedures in my project and of that in the database similar to a schema compare.

This project is not linked to any database at the moment because I am worried it will screw up the existing database. The existing database has hundreds of stored procedures but I'm only interested in finding out the difference between these  X or 5 stored procedures.

Is this possible using SQL Server project?

Comment: Would an [online diff tool](https://www.diffchecker.com/) be of any use to you for comparing just 5 stored procedures?

Comment: It's not really 5 stored procs. It's usually 50 + and ijust used 5 as an arbitrary number.

Comment: So you want to compare 50x50?  What are you looking for?

Comment: So essentially, say I have 30 SQL scripts in my project. I use this project as a way to version control my scripts. However, we update scripts through SSMS so I want a way to know which scripts have changed and is different from what is in my SQL Server Project. I only want the differences of the script in my Project and nothing else.

Comment: This is a little side note. A great tool I use to compare two sotred procedures is UltraCompare. You get I think 30 free days when you download it and if you like enough maybe you cna talk someone into a license.

Comment: Duplicate question: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685053/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases-schema-and-data

Comment: I've done something like this by exporting the X number of scripts in sys.all_sql_modules.definition to text files, then using BeyondCompare to compare the db script file to the project script file. Clumsy and tedious, but for my one-off assignment it worked better than other attempts.

Comment: Note: I DO NOT work for this company.  But I used this product extensively in a smaller company when we had to do source diffs on SQL, anything from stored procedures to table schemas, and it worked fast and accurately, including when required to do full table rebuilds.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to compare store procedures in SQL Server.

1. compare scripts of two procedures

select procedure script by using the following query

```
 SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(p.object_id) FROM sys.procedures p
```

& then compare with script of another procedure.

2 :

```
 SELECT p.modify_date FROM sys.procedures p
```

select modify date of procedure and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to make a script to dump all procedure's definitions that you want to compare on the database to separate files named with the procedure's names and then I'd make another script to run a diff between the scripts dumped in a specific directory vs the scripts under version control and direct the output to a file. Maybe using PowerShell is a good way to go to do it or even batch. All that this script should do is to iterate through the directory contents of the dumped scripts and fetch the script with the same name on the version controlled directory tree, and the script would compare one by one directing the outputs to a file showing the diffs.