# Why is the SELECT results different between SQL Query and DbDataReader Read()

Tags: c#, sql, select, sql-server-ce, idbcommand

In my code I am trying to CREATE INDEX in my code, and since CREATING duplicated INDEX is not allowed, I wanted to check if my INDEX existed in my SQL CE Database.

In C# code, I ran the query using `IDbCommand` with query `"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytablename'"` so if there are results, I have the INDEX already created for this Database. Nothing fancy. However, when I run this, I did not see the result even though I know I created the index.

So I tried just running the query using [SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1). I am seeing that I have the INDEX with the tool's querying. I thought my SQL syntax might be wrong so I ran query `"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES"` without WHERE to compare how many results I receive. I am seeing 13 results vs 12 results. Obviously the missing one is mytablename.

Does anybody have clue why this weird issue is occuring? If this is does not resolve, I can try catch and catch if there is duplicate and ignore the result. But preferably, I would like to properly catch if the Row exists or not.

The C# code I used is following.

```
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
    using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "xxxx";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            IDbCommand cmd = factory.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytablename'";
            DbDataReader ddr = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddr.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytablename' yields 12, but toolbox shows 13?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. I took out WHERE so SQL Query is `SELECT Count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES` yields 12 but toolbox shows 13. And given I CREATE(ed) INDEX specifically right before this statement, I should see 13. (which toolbox is correct)

Comment: That's truly odd... is it possible (I know this is strange) that you somehow have duplicate indices that the I_S.Indexes is only counting as one?

Comment: I just blasted a table with every different combination of index I could think of and checked schema each time - the number was correct going up (loop) and coming back down (remove loop). I cannot seem to replicate our condition.

Comment: Have you used any commercial comparison kits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685053/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases-schema-and-data

Comment: Let me give it a shot

Comment: Did you find out what was causing this?