# Database schema comparison - comparison of SQL Objects [ Tables, Views, Procedures, Triggers, Functions]

Tags: sql, database, comparison, schema

I have a Database and I did some changes on development database,
So, i have to compare the Client database and Development database. While comparing the database i came to know that several tools are been used for costs.

I have to use the tool with free of cost. Is there any tools having with free of cost while compare the databases on SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is best tool to compare two SQL Server databases (schema and data)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685053/what-is-best-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases-schema-and-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://alternativeto.net to search for alternative to the current software that you are using

I recommend on SQL forge products, you have free trial.

Comment: Hi sir,Thanks for sharing, Let me check

Comment: is there any free tools like Adeptsql Diff ...?

Comment: ApexSQL Diff supports SQL Server 2012. Haven't tested it on SQL Server 2012, but it works fine on 2008.
Advancor Database Compare is a great tool and supports SQL Server 2016.

Comment: 14 days free trial