# SQL Server ArcSDE analyze

Tags: sql-server

We have two SQL Servers: 2008 and 2008R2 which are used in accordance with ArcSDE. SQL Server 2008 database became dissociated by the hands of some people: datatype fields have changed, some column names have changed, some triggers dissapeared. We don't much care about the data itself, b/c SQL Server 2008 is for development and testing and we can always get it back from archives.

Is there a way to analyze the differences (automatically) instead of going manually field by field with our eyes and fixing it on the fly? Does SQL Server Management Studio support this functionality?

Comment: A lot of information is given in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/tool-to-compare-sql-server-tables

Comment: That is somewhat usefull.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ArcGIS Toolbox tool - Feature Compare.

Use this with the SCHEMA_ONLY option to compare feature classes.

If ArcGIS Desktop is not available but ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Engine is, the Python option is available.  The Python option can also be used to iterate over feature classes or tables.

If none of the ArcGIS products are available, there are a bunch of [scripting](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/28/comparing-sql-server-table-schemas-with-powershell/) and [GUI](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/07/31/sql-server-how-to-compare-the-schema-of-two-databases-with-schema-compare/) options out there.