# Find difference between a table on many server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

On my work we have a database on our server. But for some clients we implement on ther server the database. The problem comes when We change a table design on our server. We need to replicate that change manually on every client server.
Is there a way to see the difference of a table or all tables to know what tables or store procedures needs to be updated.

Comment: you could track it manually.  consider creating a table named lastModified with one row for each SQL object (table, view, sp, function)  Along with the object, store a timestamp of when it was last modified.  After the table exists on the client server, you can query it to determine which objects changed since their last update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post on stackoverflow with list of tools to do a Schema compare: [What is a free tool to compare two SQL Server Databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/free-tool-to-compare-sql-server-tables)

Additionally if you have VS 2010 Premium or Ultimate you can do a schema compare : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250%28v=vs.100%29.aspx