# How can I compare 2 sql server databases schema and get the update script

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if there is such a tool... given 2 sql server databases, I want the tool to tell me what is different between the 2 and give me the update script. I.e. create indexes, create table, create relationship, etc... I don't need data comparing, just schema.

Comment: Redgate makes a tool which can do that.

Comment: This looks like it would be useful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a free tool to compare two SQL Server Databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/what-is-a-free-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is really popular, but it's not free.

[Apex SQL](http://www.apexsql.com/)

If your using SQL Server 2005 or 2008. You can try these

[SQL Server Database Comparison Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool)

[DB Comparer](http://dbcomparer.com/)

You can also use the Schema Compare option in SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate versions come with a Schema Comparison tool (TOOLS | SQL Server | New Schema Comparison...)

There is more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT) has a schema compare tool, with an option to generate an update script. The example image below is version 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [xSQL Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql). It can compare any object in the database and generate synchronization scripts for all of the differences or just the ones you choose. Also, you can use it for free if you are using SQL Server Express. 

 
Disclosure: I'm affiliated with xSQL.