# Entity Framework Schema Comparer

Tags: entity-framework, database-schema

Let's my scenario:

We have a legacy database model.
This model, isn't equals to all of our customers.
We don't have access to the customer's databases.

How can we compare the database schemas from our model and our customers and apply changes to the new model?

Tnks!

Comment: One way to do this is using the Schema Comparison inside VS. With this, you point to the source and target databases and VS generate the Compare scripts for you. We use this at our company and it works great. It's under Tools > SQL Server > New Schema Comparison. If you don't have this, you need to install the SSDT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a free tool to compare two SQL Server Databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/what-is-a-free-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases)

Comment: Ok, and how I will deploy this to our customers?

Comment: 'Cause our customers/technicians, don't have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: You could copy the database schema (no data) and do the compare on site. Otherwise you will need a tool like red gate. Depends on number of clients and budget. Moving forward you could use code first migrations.