# Microsoft SQL Server : finding columns differences between two separate databases

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to have a small test that I can run to compare two separate databases that could be almost identical in table structures.

Here is what I'm looking at...

```
MSSQLSERVER (Instance)
|  
|-- MY_DB1 
    |
    |-- Table_A 
        |-- Column_Foo
        |-- Column_Boo
|-- MY_DB2
    |
    |-- Table_A
        |-- Column_Foo
        |-- Column_WTF
        |-- Column_Boo
```

Excuse the crude diagram above, this was just to illustrate the idea. As you can see we have a SQL Server instance `MSSQLSERVER` and it has two separate restored databases. Both of these databases have multiple database tables. I need this test to compare both `MY_DB1` and `MY_DB2` databases and show me a list of any tables that have different columns.

Based on above example, the output would indicate:

```
MY_DB2 
|
|-- Table_A 
    |-- Column_WTF
```

It would show `Column_WTF` because this was not found in the `MY_DB1`.

I always need to know if the columns are a 100% match, if they are not then it should provide output that would indicate where the differences are.

I would like to do this with T-SQL, but I'm also open to any opensource tools that may already have this functionality for simple comparison.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio?  It comes with some strong diff tools.

Comment: To do this with sql you need to look at sys.tables and sys.columns. You would also want to dig into the datatypes and make sure they are the same. But honestly doing a compare yourself gets really deep really fast once you start getting into defaults, constraints, foreign keys etc. There are plenty of third party tools that do this quite nicely.

Comment: What Sean said.

Comment: Any recommendations on free opensource tools to do heavy-lifting?

Comment: Here's a thread to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193438/what-is-a-free-tool-to-compare-two-sql-server-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select [Table_Catalog]
      ,[Table_Schema]
      ,[Table_Name]
      ,[Column_Name]
      ,Cnt = sum(1) over (Partition By [Table_Name],[Column_Name])
 From (
        Select * From [My_DB1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        Union All
        Select * From [My_DB2].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       ) A
) 
Select * From cte Where Cnt=1
```

Comment: John this is awesome, it might be exactly what i need. I just ran the query and it gave me some super valuable results. Much appreciated!

Comment: @jremi Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Imo, the simplest approach is to generate the DDL for the two databases and use difftool (from Visual Studio) to compare the DDL.

In SSMS, right-click your DB (MY_DB1), "Script database as", "Create to", File.
Repeat for MY_DB2.

From the (visual studio) "Developers command prompt": devenv.exe /diff file1 file2

The file arguments must have the full path to the files.